# Read in matrix without row and column names in R

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to read in the following matrix in R, but then discard the row and column names:

```
    A       B       C       D
A   0       4562    50714   882
B   5718    2302    47      26
C   72055   82      5889    215
D   1930    41      85      396
```

I do this:

```
matrix1 <-read.table("matrix_min.csv", header=T, sep=",")
m <- as.matrix(matrix1)
```

However, the resulting 'm' still has the row and column names. How do I get rid of them?

For some reason, on reading in the file using

```
matrix1 <-read.table("matrix_min.csv", header=T, sep=",")
m <- as.matrix(matrix1,row.names=0,col.names=0)
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- NULL
print(m)
```

produces:

```
     [,1] [,2]    [,3]   [,4]    [,5] 
[1,] "A"  "    0" "4562" "50714" "882"
[2,] "B"  " 5718" "2302" "   47" " 26"
[3,] "C"  "72055" "  82" " 5889" "215"
[4,] "D"  " 1930" "  41" "   85" "396"
```

Comment: `rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- NULL`?

Comment: `dimnames(m) <- NULL`

Comment: thanks, for some reason, on reading in the file using matrix1 <-read.table("matrix_min.csv", header=T, sep=","); rownames(matrix1) produces [1] "1" "2" "3" "4". Does not do away with the 'A'...'D' row names

Comment: edited question to reflect new comments. It does not matter whether I use rownames(m) <- NULL or dimnames(m) <- NULL. same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `header = TRUE` and `row.names = 1` to read in the first row and first column as dimension names.

```
dat <- data.matrix(read.csv("matrix_min.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1,
                           sep = ","))
```

Then, as suggested in the comments, use `dimnames<-` to remove the dimension names:

```
dimnames(dat) <- NULL
```